# Removing all weight painting on a bone?

Tags: weight-painting

I am very new to blender and im trying to make a player model for gmod. but the thing is that inside the head theres weight paint. which i cant reach.
So im wondering if theres a way to remove ALL weight paint on a specific bone. I have tried to find a tool for that but it just destroys everything.

Thank you.

Comment: The weights are all stored in the vertex groups in the mesh panel (in the properties window). You can do whatever you want with them there.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go into editmode and select everything.
2. Go in the Properties Panel to Object Data (The Triangle Symbol) and go to Vertex Groups.
3. Select the Vertex Group that is named exactly like your bone.
4. Set Weight to 0.
5. Click Assign.

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

The above answer applies to 2.79, in 2.80 it is very similar except that:

1. Go into EDIT mode and select the whole model - you can also do this in your SCENE COLLECTION window.
2. Go to the OBJECT DATA editor (Green Vertex Triangle) above MATERIAL editor, and go to Vertex Groups.
3. Click the required bone, and click REMOVE button under Vertex Groups pane. This removes all weight from that bone.
4. Repeat for every bone needed.

The ASSIGN button does the opposite, and assigns the whole mesh to a bone. Useful for global bones.